# How to get the object?

Tags: javascript, object

```
 - Object {9: Object}

   9: Object

   11: Object
```

When i log this object on console, it has one object:9, but when i click it, there are two objects in it, how to get the object 11?

Sorry,I don't have enough reputation to upload an image to show the problem.

Comment: be little more clear...are you trying like this? `var  Object ={9: Object};
           console.log(Object);`

Comment: Generic title and very unclear. Next time provide more informations to us.

Comment: Show your code example ..

Comment: thanks~ I have solved this problem,but I still can't understand how this happened. that object is showed on the Chrome console(F12)，when i log  it, it shows one object:9  but i click it ,it shows two in it~ sorry,my english is not very good,don't know if this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

```js
var object = {
  foo: {
    bar: 'hello'
  },
  qux: {
    baz: 'world'
  }
};

console.log(object.foo); // {bar: "hello"}
// or
console.log(object['foo']); // {bar: "hello"}
```